# On few machine I get - 'css was ignored due to mime type mismatch'

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-9

I have deployed my ASP.NET on the production server. It has been working properly but recently I came to know that in one of the client machine with IE9 (of same version as mine) the site is not rendering properly - does not load up the CSS and javascripts.

When I got the screenshot of F12 (dev tool in IE9) from client, I found that all the CSS errors had this message - "**css was ignored due to mime type mismatch**" and the javascript showed - 'SCRIPT1002: Syntax Error'

Any suggestion is highly appreciated. I have tried all that came to my mind... I am lost now/

**here is the response HTML that is recieved at client -**

Site

```
    <script src="/Utility/global.js?Version=2.1.61120.2" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js?Version=2.1.61120.2" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/global.js?Version=2.1.61120.2" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style type="text/css"> body { font-size: 84%; } </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Themes/default/style/Global.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Themes/default/style/Common.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Themes/default/style/common_print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Themes/default/style/forum.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Themes/default/style/forum_print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
    <script src="/Utility/global.js?Version=2.1.61120.2" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Themes/default/style/projects.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Themes/default/style/sticky-footer.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Themes/default/style/blog.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Themes/default/style/menu.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Comment: Show an example of how you include your css and js

Answer (score 0):

Is CSS inline (inside <style> tags), imported (@import inside <style>) or external (<link>)? If imported or external, is it on CDN and what is the "Content-Type" HTTP response header sent? If internal, does your <style> contains the "type" attribute?

Comment: I have updated my post - it shows how the CSS files are added in the Head section. I am using external CSS and the CSS is present in the sub-folder. Content-type is 'text/css'

Comment: Can you make sure "/Themes/default/style/___.css" returns a "Content-Type: text/css" as well? Or does it return "text/plain", "text/html", etc?

Comment: Could you please tell me How can I ensure that "/Themes/default/style/___.css" returns "Content-Type: text/css"? 
This is what I see in Fiddler on my machine for one of the CSS - 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/css
Content-Encoding: gzip
Last-Modified: Mon, 13 Jun 2011 09:24:12 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "046e7a7ab29cc1:0"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
P3P: CP=" OTI CURi OUR IND ONL DEM "
Set-Cookie: RPSMaybe=;path=/;expires=Thu, 30-Oct-1980 16:00:00 GMT;
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
P3P: CP="OTI CURi OUR IND ONL DEM"
Date: Wed, 15 Jun 2011 18:51:17 GMT
Content-Length: 3538

Comment: That's exactly what I'm talking about: "HTTP/1.1 200 OK Content-Type: text/css"... Both IE versions are the same, but is security configs the same? Can you make a test removing <script> and <link> tags until you find a culprit?

Comment: security config is also same, I tried with the same credentials and it works fine. What do you feel the culprit could be?...so that I can try focus on finding it out

Comment: Funny part that I just heard from client is... When one of the link was clicked then that page loaded absolutely fine... and now when client comes back to the original page then even that page is working fine..

Comment: Possibly a transient connection error: your client received a "connection reset" when he was loading one (or all) CSS/JS. If you *really* wants to test this theory, you can ask your client to reset his cache and try again. If it works, the problem was transient.

Comment: I had already asked the client to clear all cache and try again. But the problem persisted.
It happens on IE9 only.

Comment: And the "solution" (clicking a link)?

Comment: Yes, clicking that particular does the trick and not sure why? even though the other page is using the same master page as by the earlier page

Answer (score 0):

Check the headers with curl

```
curl -I http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

Next go to AWS S3 console, go to the file > properties > metadata and confirm they are set.

IE can be very particular about content types.

[image]